# solr Security help

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, apache-2.2

I have solr setup with Jetty on my Ubuntu server.

On any computer now, I can type my_ip:8983/solr/ and the page will show upp to anybody.

How can I disable this so that only I can access that port and the solr admin?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You best option is to to configure a firewall rule to prevent connections based on source. You can restrict what ips update the index in the [config](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrResin#Restricting_Updates_.28Security.29) or enable authentication but neither of thes options give you what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

IP address restriction is not an acceptable solution, one would like to manage Solr from a dynamic IP which is allocated by my ISP.

It can be done via tomcat.

```
In etc/webdefault.xml add this inside the <web-app> block:

<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Solr Administration</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>solr-admin</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
  <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
  <realm-name>Solr Administration</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

tried it and it works. thanks Chris Adams http://acdha.tumblr.com/post/207608584/jetty-solr-password-cheatsheet